# Websphere 7 jconsole support but with memory and threads

Tags: java, websphere, jconsole

I went through these steps and got jconsole to connect to IBM websphere but the memory is greyed out and disabled, I want to be able to monitor memory usage in real time.  I see the mbeans configuration.  I basically want to use jconsole to connect to a local websphere server and gather the real time changes in memory.  I see those tabs greyed out but MBEANS section available. How do I get the memory to show?

```
set WAS_HOME=C:/Program Files (x86)/ibm/WebSphere/AppServer
set JAVA_HOME=%WAS_HOME%/java
echo %WAS_HOME%
set CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%/lib/jconsole.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%WAS_HOME%/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.0.0.jar

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%WAS_HOME%/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.0.0.jar

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%WAS_HOME%/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.orb_8.0.0.jar

set HOST=localhost

set PORT=9100

&quot;%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jconsole&quot; -J-Djava.class.path=&quot;%CLASSPATH%&quot; ^

service:jmx:iiop://%HOST%:%PORT%/jndi/JMXConnector
```

Do you see any security issues here?  Will the jmx connection iiop allow me to see the memory data?

Comment: Have you considered using [IBM Health Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.doc/topics/introduction.html) instead of jconsole?

Comment: I could look at it, will it work with IBM Websphere 7

Comment: Some of those tools look interesting, I am using the IBM Support Assistance Workbench but can't tell which one is a real time analyzer with graph.  A lot of the tools look like heap analyzer.

Comment: If you add `-Xhealthcenter` to your WAS generic JVM settings and restart the server, you should be able to connect with Health Center to your running server, and clicking the GC link should take you to the memory usage graph.

Comment: That works, I added all these settings though, -agentlib:healthcenter -Xtrace:output=perfmon.out  -Xhealthcenter.  You can set the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To monitor basic parameters of the IBM JVM you can could use [IBM Health Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.doc/topics/introduction.html) instead of jConsole. It can be installed either as a add on to IBM Support Assistant, or as plugin to Eclipse (from Eclipse Marketplace).

Depending on your Java version and path level you would need to enable it via generic JVM settings:

- For Java Version 7 and later, Version 6 service refresh 5 and later, and Version 5 service refresh 10 and later use `-Xhealthcenter`
- For Version 6 service refreshes 1 through 4, and Version 5 service refreshes 8 and 9 - use `-agentlib:healthcenter -Xtrace:output=perfmon.out`

Check the details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.doc/topics/enablingagent.html).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you are connecting to WebSphere's MBean server (and not the platform MBean server which is created automatically by the JRE) and that the relevant MBeans are not registered there. One solution is therefore to cross-register them in WebSphere's MBean server. The VisualWAS project provides an [add-on](https://github.com/veithen/visualwas#websphere-plugin-installation) for WebSphere that does this.